# Can PHP Code Sniffer advise me which rule has been violated and how to turn it off?

Tags: php, laravel, phpcodesniffer

Is it possible to have the sniffer output the rule has been broken and therefore which line of my config I can change to stop these violations appearing?

e.g. I am getting a large number of array related violations but I am happy with my array indentation. How can I find out the rule and how do I disable it?

Thanks

```
 494 | ERROR | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected
     |       |     20 space(s) but found 1
 495 | ERROR | [x] Array key not aligned correctly; expected 19
     |       |     spaces but found 12
 495 | ERROR | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected
     |       |     22 space(s) but found 1
 496 | ERROR | [x] Array key not aligned correctly; expected 19
     |       |     spaces but found 12
 496 | ERROR | [x] Array double arrow not aligned correctly; expected
     |       |     25 space(s) but found 1
 497 | ERROR | [x] Array key not aligned correctly; expected 19
     |       |     spaces but found 12
```

Comment: How are you calling it? `phpcs -s myfile.php`

Comment: Oh! -s gets me the rule, thanks! I did look at the docs, promise

Comment: Np, I made it an answer. Hopefully helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-s` argument, it's listed under "Printing Full and Summary Reports" in the [docs](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Reporting#printing-full-and-summary-reports).

e.g. `phpcs -s myfile.php`

To answer the second part of your question, there are multiple ways to ignore specific sniffs. You can do it inline using comments and the `phpcs:disable` syntax, or you can use command line arguments to exclude specific sniffs which seems like more what you want:

`phpcs --exclude=Generic.PHP.LowerCaseConstant,Some.Other.Rule myfile.php`